# google geocoding api city vs highway

Tags: api, geocoding

I need to know if it's possible to check, if i'm currently in a city or on a highway/outside of a city using the geocoding API.

I know there is some kind of viewport returned by the api, but i'm not very happy with it.

I want to make a difference in the zooming level of the map.

Thanks,

Carsten